# C++ Is "const void" As Return Value More Const-Correct Than "void"?

Tags: c++, constants, void

I have become somewhat of a const-correctness fanatic when it comes to programming. I've got const's everywhere (where correct of course). Now I've even started const'ing my void return types.

You can't create a void object and therefore you can't assign a value to a void object even if it's const or not, which means the "const" becomes redundant.

So am I const'ing my void return types for nothing?

I hope this isn't too philosophical for Stack Overflow.

TL;DR:

```
const void Foo( void );
```

vs

```
void Foo( void );
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: No, it makes no sense to return `const void` because returning void signifies returning nothing.

Comment: While you're going const crazy, why not do this `const void const Foo( const void const );`

Comment: While VC++ doesn't warn about returning `const void`, It does warn about taking `const void` as an argument.

Comment: actually in C++11 returning const values is a quite bad idea, not just for void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `const void` is completely meaningless. I'm surprised your compiler doesn't give you a warning, actually. Clang, for instance, told me:

```
example.cpp:1:1: warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect
      [-Wignored-qualifiers]
const void Foo( void );
^~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Hmm, VC++ doesn't give me any errors. Didn't realize it's the same deal with all return types, though. That's why I couldn't find a duplicate question before I posted.