# What is const void, and is it a valid return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, void

The description of [`std::is_void`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_void) states that:

> Provides the member constant value  that is equal to true, if T is the **type void, const void, volatile
> void,** or const volatile void.

Then what could be `const void`, or a `volatile void` ?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28707034/264325) states that `const void` return type would be invalid (however compiles on VC++ 2015)

```
const void foo() { }
```

If by standard, `const void` is invalid (VC being wrong) - then what is `const void`?

Comment: The answer you link to doesn't state that it would be invalid, it states that it would be "meaningless", which I would take to mean "doesn't offer any benefits over `void` without `const`".

Comment: @hvd, the answer states that compiler should warn/error about such qualification. By that I presume C++ standard doesn't allow qualifications with `void`

Comment: The answer states that the compiler should warn about such qualification, it doesn't mention an error, and an error would be wrong. That remark is just about quality of implementation, not about conformance, but I can understand that that's not at all clear from the remark itself.

Comment: @Ajay the standard doesn't specify that there should be a warning when you use meaningless code. It was a decision by gcc to give you an additional hint that this code doesn't do anything. But VC isn't wrong in any way.

Comment: @Ajay The answer states that clang gives a warning, and that, in the author's opinion, other compilers should. If the standard didn't allow it, it would be an error, not a warning.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`const void` is a type which you can form a pointer to. It's similar to a normal void pointer, but conversions work differently. For example, a `const int*` cannot be implicitly converted to a `void*`, but it can be implicitly converted to a `const void*`. Likewise, if you have a `const void*` you cannot `static_cast` it to an `int*`, but you can `static_cast` it to a `const int*`.

```
const int i = 10;
void* vp = &i;                           // error
const void* cvp = &i;                    // ok
auto ip = static_cast<int*>(cvp);        // error
auto cip = static_cast<const int*>(cvp); // ok
```

Comment: While your answer is good, it doesn't state the reason of `const void`, but its all around void and non-void pointers [ with (non-)const-ness ].

Comment: @Ajay: I disagree. A `const void*` is the only reason you would ever see `const void`. It might be passed around as a template argument, but that argument type will only ever be instantiated with a `*` at the end of it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You may also see `const void` in [question asked by language lawyer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312668)

Comment: @Ajay: At some point this question becomes a philosophy question. The "reason" of `const void` is that all types in C++ can be made `const`. It "exists" in the same way that `void` exists. @Benjamin Lindley's answer explains what it is by way of when you see it and how you use it.

Answer (score 25):

As `void`, `const void` is a void type. However, if `const void` is a *return* type, the `const` is meaningless (albeit legal!), because [[expr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of
>   the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

However, it is a valid type itself and occurs in e.g. [C-standard library functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), where it's used to ensure const-correctness of argument pointers: `int const*` cannot be converted to `void*`, but `void const*`.

Comment: `const void` as a return type does affect the function type, so it's not completely meaningless.

Comment: @cpplearner Except it is in every practical sense, because neither the *signature* of the function nor the type of a call to it are affected.

Comment: Well it can change the signature of a function template. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @cpplearner Fair enough - it still is a waste of keystrokes, though.

Comment: We normally see: const int * cannot go to void *, but const void *.

Answer (score 20):

Types can be the result of templates; a template might state `const T`, and be instantiated with `T` as `void`.

The linked answer is misled, or rather, limited in view in that it regards the special case of a non-template type, and even then `const void` might be *meaningless*, but it is *valid code*.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a need to use const void in the implementation of a lookup table. My intention was to create a list of constant pointers to routines.

When creating the routines, I need to have a const void return in order to prevent the compiler from complaining.

```
const void lookup_1(void* v)
{
    printf("This is lookup 1\r\n");
}

const void lookup_2(void* v)
{
    printf("This is lookup 2\r\n");
}


const void(*lookup_table[])(void*) =
{
    lookup_1,
    lookup_2
}
```

It doesn't look particularly aesthetic but I haven't found a more elegant way of doing what I intend.  So to sum-up I would say it's perfectly reasonable to use in this context and maybe others that I haven't considereda.