# Should I declare method "const" if it is "shallow const" only, not "deep const"?

Tags: c++, constants, shallow-clone

I have class `Foo` and its member `bar_` is a pointer to some data. Method `modify` modifies the data, but not the pointer itself. Therefore I can declare the method as *const*:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : bar_(new double) {};
    void modify() const {*bar_ += 1;};
private:
    double *bar_;
};
```

If I declare the method as *const*, it will accessible from other const methods, which is more flexible. At the same time I can drop *const* as a hint for other developers and users that method modifies the data indirectly (and let think that the data is owned by the class). So I have a choice here: declare `modify` as *const* or drop *const*: `void modify() const` or `void modify()`.

**What are pros and cons of each approach? What do guidelines say? What should I do?**

Comment: Hope this explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881475/12861639

Comment: There is no universal law that says where the class method should or should not be `const` here. This is up to you to decide.

Comment: Classes can have `mutable` members that `const` functions *can* modify. Whether or not a function should be `const` really depends on whether it is "logically const" - doesn't modify the object in any meaningful observable way.

Comment: With modern C++, as per Herb Sutter, the const is also supposed to be robust for multithreading.  So having mutable state with const ought to be a strong guarantee of safe logical const.  And that's a bit more work, such as using atomic or mutex protection.

Comment: @Eljay At least it's generally a good idea since multithreading is a thing. Still, not making a component thread-safe can be a significant cost-saving.

Comment: What does "shallow const" mean??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const` after a method declaration is a statement of intent - `const` methods are meant to be idempotent; they do not modify the state of the object and can be called on `const` instances.

If the value pointed-to by `bar_` is part of the object's state, then a `const` method should not modify it.

In addition, even the name `modify()` sounds like it modifies the object in some way, and thus should not be declared `const`.

But also the other way is important - if a method does not modify the state, it is recommended to declare it `const` (see C++ Core Guideline [Con.2](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rconst-fct)).